# Xamarin Android AppCompat drawer (and toolbar) does not display fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-appcompat

i work on xamarin android project and and i followed this [tutorial](https://xmonkeys360.com/2018/01/24/create-android-navigation-drawer-layout-using-support-design/).
note: in this tutorial i create  navigation drawer using support design .

this tutorial is ok and i created it . but when i added a fragment to the **MainActivity** , It was not loaded !

activity_main.xmal:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <include
                layout="@layout/toolbar" />
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/HomeFrameLayout"
                android:minWidth="25px"
                android:minHeight="25px"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: FragmentUnLoaded]

But,If you change its location to the beginning of `android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout` like this :

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/HomeFrameLayout"
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <include
                layout="@layout/toolbar" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

fragment is loaded ! but Part of it goes below toolbar !

[image: loadedButUnderToolbar]

note :The image above is a **TextView** (under toolbar)

**HomeFrameLayout**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ff46a2fd"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">
        <TextView
            android:text="Text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView1" />
        <TextView
            android:text="Text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView2" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

where is the problem from ? How should I repair it to be fully loaded?

Comment: What's in your `FrameLayout`? Could you share a project?

Comment: @BillyLiu-MSFT updated post and add fragmentLayout , for test i added two TextView But they are Below toolbar !